# Poor performance on Scope that uses a foreign key on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am getting very poor performance when calling the scope below. I am trying to identify products that have a Status > 100 which don't have a category assigned. When I remove the category_id part of the scope, performance is great. Is this because it is a foreign key? Do I have to express this in a different way?

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :category

 scope :uncategorised_and_trending, -> { where( "status > ?", 100).where(category_id: nil).order('end_date DESC') }

end
```

Using Rails 4.1

Comment: Do you have an index defined on `products.category_id`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @vee. I do, but unfortunately it made no difference.

Comment: Are you sure it's inclusion of `category_id` in the query that's causing performance bottleneck?  You have `status` in your where clause, and a order both of which contribute to the performance.  Also, how many records are we talking about here?

Comment: Hey @vee when using just status I have no issues at all. Total of around 400 000 records.

Comment: I'm assuming `where( "status > ?", 100).order('end_date DESC')` when you say `status` only.  How much time difference is it? also have you checked the time for executing just `where(category_id: nil)`?  Unsure of the issue, hence the reason for multiple questions.